# How to call api on background thread in Roboelectric in Android

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm running a test with Robolectric runner. The code under test verifies it's not executed on the main thread:

```
if (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == java.lang.Thread.currentThread()) {
    new IllegalStateException("Method called on the UI thread");
}
```

The Robolectric test raises this exception, and I don't want that. I tried running the code from a `Robolectric.getBackgroundScheduler()`, but I'm still getting the exception.

How can my test run in a different thread?

Answer (score 1):

The main idea in testing multithreading code is to make it run in controlled way on a single thread.

What I would do:

1. Move checking code to some class helper
2. Inject it and mock it under the test

Pluses of this solution:

1. It will resolve your issue
2. It will remove duplication and move you closer to SRP (single class responsibility principle)

Minuses:

1. It requires proper naming since it will hide functionality behind method
2. It will give you additional flexibility that you might not need

Success!